# Is codename one is good technology as per user interface is concerned

Tags: codenameone

I am working on an application that need to be run on android and ios. I haven't decided the technology yet.This application will have rich user interface that contains 2D and 3D graphs, charts and lot of tables. I came across Codename one that looks promising for cross platform application but i'm not sure its good for rich ui having graphs and table.Is this technology feasible for rich user interface?

Answer (score 0):

There are charting libraries for Codename One which you can see in the [cn1lib section](http://codenameone.com/cn1libs.html). I'm not sure if they offer 3D charts. In terms of UI richness, its really related to your skill as a developer/designer more than anything else.